# yii2 Query data provider with multiple not and or

Tags: yii2, null

Hello everyone :slight_smile:

i try to show 2 gridviews of datas.
a first gridview where any of three fields is empty (so if one or two of thoses fields are empty, it should show the entry)

and a second gridview with the records that have those 3 fields filled up.

i do something wrong, because if the date field is entered, then the record goes from the first to the second gridview, event if the 2 other fields remain empty…

this is my code :
(dataprovider is the second gridview and unprocessed is the first)

```
if(Yii::$app->user->can('admin')){
      $searchModel = new DeliverySearch();
      $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
      $dataProvider->query->orderBy(['delivery_expedition_date'=>SORT_DESC]);
    }
    elseif(Yii::$app->user->can('maker')){
      $maker = Maker::find()->where(['user_id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->one();
      $searchModel = new DeliverySearch();
      $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
      $dataProvider->query->andWhere(['maker_id'=>$maker->id]);
      //$dataProvider->query->where(['and',['not',['delivery_trackcode' => null,'delivery_carrier' => null,'delivery_expedition_date' => null]]]);
      $dataProvider->query->andWhere(['not', ['delivery_trackcode' => null]]);
      $dataProvider->query->andWhere(['not', ['delivery_carrier' => null]]);
      $dataProvider->query->andWhere(['not', ['delivery_expedition_date' => null]]);
      $dataProvider->query->orderBy(['delivery_expedition_date'=>SORT_DESC]);

      $unProcessed = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
      $unProcessed->query->andWhere(['maker_id'=>$maker->id]);
      $unProcessed->query->andWhere(['or',['delivery_trackcode'=> NULL],['delivery_carrier'=> NULL],['delivery_expedition_date'=> NULL]]);
      $unProcessed->query->orderBy(['created_at'=>SORT_DESC]);
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'unProcessed' => $unProcessed,
    ]);
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :slight_smile:
kind regards

Answer (score 0):

So, i finally found the solution. the expedition date need to be check if NULL or not, but the carrier and trackcode need to be checked for empty ('') and not for NULL

```
 ->query->andWhere(['not', ['delivery_trackcode' => null]]);
  ->query->andWhere(['not', ['delivery_carrier' => null]]);
```